# How to decouple code behind with business logic?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interfaces, coupling, xamarin

I'm having a hard time to decouple two classes.

I have my code behind (will call it "class A") that I use to tweak the interface (defined in xaml).

Next I have a class B that is only logic. But while the logic is executing I have to update the UI.

My problem is that I can't "return" from the class B back to A to update the UI because B has not finished working. And I can't give the view itself to modifiy to B because it would couple A and B.

I suppose that I have to use some interfaces logic but I don't know how.

For example :

```
Class A
{
     private void OnClickEvent()
     {
         var B = new(B);
         b.work();
     }

     private void UpdateUI()
     {
        ...
     }
}


Class B
{
    public void work()
    {
        while (...)
        {
             ...
             //Here, how to call A.UpdateUI() ?
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What you're talking about is performing an *asynchronous* call to another method.  You want work to be running in the background while you keep calling UpdateUI.

Comment: the code executed inside the B.work() in non blocant. So I don't need it to be called from background :-)

Comment: So:  `private void OnClickEvent()
     {
         var B = new(B);
         b.work();
         UpdateUI();
     }`.  If `work()` is taking too long, then yes, you need to call it asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. But if in B.work() I could just call the right methods from A it would be a lot simpler than returning a lot of differents return codes to know what I should call in A. I don't have only one method to call that belong in A... Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: I'm assuming B is a dependency of A here.  That means A calls B, not the other way around.  If it is inconvenient for A to call B, then there is a problem with how your code is organized that should be addressed.  In other words, if it is correct for A to call B.work(), then make it such that A can also call UpdateUI.  Otherwise, make the appropriate changes and get back to me.  ;)

Comment: Its normal for A to call B and A can call updateUI() because its a method from A. Thx for your answers by the way ;-)

Comment: I was hoping for this kind of solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784215/what-does-decoupling-two-classes-at-the-interface-level-mean But maybe the 2 problems don't have anything in common...

Comment: Is it possible to use MVVM and get rid of the code-behind A class?

Comment: You may consider using a delegate based solution. Define a delegate in class B, initialize with a method in class A, and then call B.work(). When the method work() is done, invoke the delegate.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso The whole projet was made using code behind. So unfortunatly no :-)

Comment: @Tushar yep its a good idear ! But is it the best OOP way ?

Comment: For updating UI I would normally use the observer pattern, which is fundamental to MV*. The view registers itself as an observer of whatever your state/model if, then B only needs to update the model which will automatically trigger a callback to update the view.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably execute `work()` asynchronously and then use events to signal the changes which might cause the UI to update. The benefit of events is that the event source does not know anything about the subscribers, so you can still keep the business logic (B) decoupled from the view (A).

Comment: I understand what you mean. But it doesn't feel to be the right solution. I would have to pass a hole lot of methods async then... Would'nt it be a little to bulky to have one event for each small UI changes ?

Comment: @Doctor: What kind of events is it which will cause UI updates?

Comment: First, in my code behind (class A) I have some functions that changes a listView's item source. Another one that removes the separators between the items of the list. And finaly, one that updates a label. All thoses are UI related so they belong to class A.  Class B now : The work() method goes through data from an API and based on this data, decides to call some or none methods from class A (Well it would if I knew how to call A's methods from B !).  For now the all the code is in A... :-)

Comment: @Doctor - a good solution for async in Wpf projects is using BackgroundWorker class. You should take a look in this.

Comment: @Emerson Cardoso Interesting indeed. Thx. But my code is not async. The loop is non blocant.

Answer (score 0):

Simply introduce an interface:

```
class A : BUpdateTarget
{
     private void OnClickEvent()
     {
         var B = new(B);
         b.work(this);
     }

     public void UpdateUI()
     {
        ...
     }
}


interface BUpdateTarget
{
    UpdateUI();
}

class B
{
    public void work(BUpdateTarget updateTarget)
    {
        while (...)
        {
             //...
             updateTarget.UpdateUI()
             //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Are you sure that this is the maximum decoupling I can get using interfaces ?

Comment: @Doctor I have no idea what you mean by "maximum decoupling". And I have fleeting feeling that this is dangerous way of thinking. Code should only be decoupled to the point of supporting current use cases. And nothing more!

Comment: I always thought that the logic should not be aware of the UI. So when I asked about the maximum decoupling, what I meant was : Does giving an interface (that represents the UI) to a logic class as parameter is a sufficient separation from the UI and the logic ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `B` class represents the logic of some user interface, while the `A` represents the code-behind class of the same user interface.

If you just can't use MVVM, I would recommend make the `B` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so it can notify the client (the `A` class) about changes in its state (like updates in a collection, for instance). Once the change occurs, `A` gets notified, and can do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: Ok thx. I'll look into it ! I always thought that this was only used for MVVM...